# ghost4j class cast exception during joining two PostScripts

Tags: java, ghostscript, postscript, ghost4j

I am trying to join two `PostScript` files to one with `ghost4j 0.5.0` as follows:

```
final PSDocument[] psDocuments = new PSDocument[2];
psDocuments[0] = new PSDocument();
psDocuments[0].load("1.ps");
psDocuments[1] = new PSDocument();
psDocuments[1].load("2.ps");
psDocuments[0].append(psDocuments[1]);
psDocuments[0].write("3.ps");
```

During this simplified process I got the following exception message for the above "append" line:

```
org.ghost4j.document.DocumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException:   
org.apache.xmlgraphics.ps.dsc.events.UnparsedDSCComment cannot be cast to 
org.apache.xmlgraphics.ps.dsc.events.DSCCommentPage
```

Until now I have not made to find out whats the problem here - maybe some kind of a problem within one of the PostScript files?

So help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I tested with ghostScript commandline tool:

```
gswin32.exe -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pswrite -sOutputFile="test.ps" --filename "1.ps" "2.ps"
```

which results in a document where 1.ps and 2.ps are merged into one(!) page (i.e. overlay).
When removing the --filename the resulting document will be a PostScript with two pages as expected.

Comment: ghost4j can't parse 2.ps, maybe there is an error in the document, I can't tell.

Comment: I thought parsing happens during the call of load() and not during append?

Comment: Btw. I have no problems with opening both PosScript files in GhostView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurs because one of the 2 documents does not follow the Adobe Document Structuring Convention (DSC), which is mandatory if you want to use the `Document` `append` method.

Use the `SafeAppenderModifier` instead. There is an example here: http://www.ghost4j.org/highlevelapisamples.html (Append a PDF document to a PostScript document)

Answer (score 1):

I think something is wrong in the document or in the XMLGraphics library as it seems it cannot parse a part of it.

Here you can see the code in ghost4j that I think it is failing ([link](https://github.com/zippy1978/ghost4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/ghost4j/document/PSDocument.java#L87)):

```
    DSCParser parser = new DSCParser(bais);
    Object tP = parser.nextDSCComment(DSCConstants.PAGES);
    while (tP instanceof DSCAtend)
        tP = parser.nextDSCComment(DSCConstants.PAGES);
    DSCCommentPages pages = (DSCCommentPages) tP;
```

And here you can see why XMLGraphics may bre sesponsable ([link](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xmlgraphics/commons/tags/commons-1_5rc1/src/java/org/apache/xmlgraphics/ps/dsc/DSCParser.java)):

```
private DSCComment parseDSCComment(String name, String value) {
    DSCComment parsed = DSCCommentFactory.createDSCCommentFor(name);
    if (parsed != null) {
        try {
            parsed.parseValue(value);
            return parsed;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //ignore and fall back to unparsed DSC comment
        }
    }
    UnparsedDSCComment unparsed = new UnparsedDSCComment(name);
    unparsed.parseValue(value);
    return unparsed;
}
```

It seems `parsed.parseValue(value)` has thrown an exception, it was hidden in the `catch` and it returned an unparsed version ghost4j didn't expect.